возврат по rvalue ссылке
Буду очень признателен если объясните зачем(я имею ввиду как их правильно и уместно использовать) может понадобиться возврат по правой ссылке (как их понимать, примеры использования) или укажете на источник который у меня по всей видимости загуглить не вышло(я пока еще правильно гуглить не научился)
